# Upload of .xlsx not working with php

Tags: php

Sending an upload to my site that is currently just run on localhost. Attempting to upload an .xlsx file gives me my predefined error of "Sorry, you cannot upload this file. Sorry, your file was not uploaded." Code follows:

```
    <?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$uploadFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($uploadFileType != "xlsx") {
    echo "Sorry, you cannot upload this file.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Form:

```
    <form id="uploadbanner" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="uploads.php">
<input id="fileupload" name="myfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What's `$uploadFileType`? Must not be `xlsx`.

Comment: Can you post the form you're using?

Comment: I'm very new to php and I didn't realize declaring `$uploadFileType` as I did wasn't declaring it as a variable relying on the output of `pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`. I'm assuming I'd need the equivalant of `$imageFileType` for `xlsx`. Is that correct?

Comment: A file input with `name="myfile"` will be in `$_FILES["myfile"]`, not `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]`. That's your fundamental issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$target_file = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
$uploadOk = 1;
$uploadFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


// Check file size
if ($_FILES["myfile"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($uploadFileType != "xlsx") {
    echo "Sorry, you cannot upload this file.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is virtually all the same code. Better to explain what you **changed** and why.

Comment: That solved the issue of filetype error. Still not allowing me to upload. Getting `Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.` Directory where it is uploaded to is set to 777. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I changed the name in the $_FILES array to match the one in the form. On the part, you should check your logs and inspect (var_dump) the content of $_FILES. There's an error parameter that could provide you with information.

Comment: Are you saying that I should add some code like `var_dump($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);` into my php script?

Comment: Realized I had made a mistake. Fixed it. True error now is that after form submission, I am left with a blank web browser page at the address of the php file. Directory for upload is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming your input file to `name="fileToUpload"` will solve your issue.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```